# How to loop through list with objects JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, object

```
finalValues = [1, 2, 3],
linksList = [
{source:0, target:1},
{source:1, target:3},
{source:2, target:1},
]
```

So I have two lists and I need to loop through linksList and in those objects I need to add new property called value and it would be equal to finalValues.

```
For example:
    linksList = [
    {source:0, target:1, value:finalValues[0]},
    {source:1, target:3, value:finalValues[1]},
    {source:2, target:1, value:finalValues[2]},
    ]
```

So first value in finalValues list would be value for first object in linksList array and so on...

Comment: what does not work? please add your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). And add the `value` based on index

```js
const finalValues = [1, 2, 3];
const linksList = [ {source:0, target:1}, {source:1, target:3}, {source:2, target:1}];

let res = linksList.map((a,b)=>({...a,value:finalValues[b]}))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const finalValues = [1, 2, 3];
const linksList = [
  {source:0, target:1},
  {source:1, target:3},
  {source:2, target:1},
];

linksList.forEach((link, index) => {
  link['value'] = finalValues[index];
})

console.log(linksList);
```